# CSS either show all elements in a single row or each element on a new row

Tags: css

I have four buttons with varying content lengths. I want all buttons to have the same dimensions as the largest button. They should all be displayed in a single row if there is sufficient space otherwise each button should be displayed on a new row. I have attached a diagram below.

[image: Paint diagram of intended element layout]

My HTML code is

```
<div class="answers">
    <button class="button">A</button><br>
    <button class="button">B</button><br>
    <button class="button">C</button><br>
    <button class="button">D</button><br>
</div>
```

I have given the following CSS properties to the container

```
.answers {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

This ensures that all the buttons are the same width but it always displays them on four lines even when there is room to have them all on a single row.

TLDR:

I need a way to make sure all the buttons have the same width as the largest button, I do not know this value as the buttons can be updated with new content.

I then need to calculate if these four buttons can fit horizontally on the screen and if not display them vertically avoiding a situation where I might have a grid of 2x2.

Comment: As flex is awesome for one dimensional direction, why don't you use here CSS grid?

Comment: I will look into it, any answer integrating it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use media queries or min/max width in css

Comment: @IamMirror the size of the buttons is not known as they feature dynamic content hence a more general solution is required.

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be like this (you can use jquery to calculate width for all buttons according to the text in the largest button)

```js
let maxWidth = 0;

$('.button').each(function(){
 const width = parseFloat($(this).css('width'));
 if(width > maxWidth) {maxWidth = width}
})

$('.button').css('width', maxWidth +'px');
```

```css
.answers {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    table-layout: fixed;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="answers">
    <button class="button">small</button><br>
    <button class="button">s</button><br>
    <button class="button">large</button><br>
    <button class="button">the largest</button><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this approach appears to only allow for buttons to be vertically stacked and fixes their width at 10%. I am trying to allow for both vertical and horizontal display along with dynamically adjusting the width of the buttons to the largest one.

Comment: @LukePrior I have updated the answer you can check now

Comment: This still does not work, the text is not centered and will often be cut-off. The buttons are also always shown as a straight row. https://imgur.com/a/VRHsQbj

Comment: I would also like a pure CSS solution if possible but I do recognize that the conditions are quite specific so this may not be possible.